# Binding between two BehaviorRelays with value transformation

Tags: swift, binding, rx-swift

I can use [RxBiBinding](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxBiBinding) to bind between two BehaviorRelay like this:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

var textFirst = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: "")
var textSecond = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: "")

(textFirst <-> textSecond).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

What I can't figure out is how to transform the string traveling between the relays?
Transformation of course is symmetric between first and second and back.

Comment: is there any errors? if so please share

Comment: there are no errors since I'm asking on how to achieve the value transformation in the first place...

Comment: Have you tried just updating the value of either of the relays?

Comment: Don't know how to attach value transformation between the binding :( 
Example:
let's say textFirst contains lowercased string, and textSecond uppercased. The transformation is trivial in code, but I don't know how to apply it to the relays in a way that textFirst.accept("hello") will result in emitting events from textSecond with value "HELLO" (and the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [RxBiBinding implemention](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxBiBinding/blob/master/RxBiBinding/Classes/RxChannel.swift) I'm not entirely sure if that's possible, sorry.

Good news is that there is a quite nice medium article that guides you through writing custom operator: https://medium.com/@dannylazarow/rxswift-reverse-observable-aka-two-way-binding-5027cbfdc6f0